# C# find string(s) with regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, get, var

I have different formats of a date (i.e.: Birthday):

Like this:

```
string Birthday = "Next Birthday Jul 30 in 2014";
string Birthday = "Birt 30 6 2014";
```

So I will create a simple function to get the vars contains this string.
I created different lines:
First I count length of "Next Birthday ", to get Month, after this I added Month to length to get day... .

Maybe there is a template solution, because I have so many schemas.

Possible Result:

```
enter code here
string month = "Jul"; // Result after "Next Birthday "
string day = "30"; // Result after "Next Birthday " + month
string year = "2014"; // Result after "Next Birthday " + month +" " + day "in "
```

Comment: use DateTime instead of strings to manipulate dates?

Comment: do you have control of the formatting?  If not you're just going to have to hunt for tokens that look like days/months/years

Comment: Hi, no there is no chance. 
So first I will read "day" "month" "year". The result will be checked by an additional function to get formated to DateTime.

Comment: I solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436381/c-sharp-regex-string-extraction