# Regex expression - split string into three variables

Tags: c#, regex, string, winforms

the string to split up looks like this:

```
192.168.1.254445.... 0000 0000 0010 = Flags: 0x002 (SYN)
```

There are three bits of information in this string that need to be pulled to different variables which are:

```
 ip - 192.168.1.254
 port - 445
 flag - SYN
```

The ip is an ip address so it will need to capture the full range of addresses.
Port can be from 1-4 digits long.
and the flag can contain three, three letter characters e.g. SYN or SYN,ACK or SYN,ACK,URG etc (e.g. different combinations of packet flags.

I have tried using Split with ( : ' ' as the splits but whenever I put in [1] as the output it creates an

```
 error - Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

I then created this code out of looking at  [C# RegEx string extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436381/c-sharp-regex-string-extraction)  :

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(<?ip>\d+)(<?port>\d+).... \d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4} = Flags: \d{1}x\d{3} ((<?flag>\w+))");
Match match = pattern.Match(dst1);
string ip = (match.Groups["ip"].Value);
string port = (match.Groups["port"].Value);
string flag = (match.Groups["flag"].Value);
string dst = ip + port + flag;
listBox1.Items.Add(dst);
```

But this returns no values in the listBox1.

If the string is changed to:

```
 192.168.1.254.... 0000 0000 0010 = Flags: 0x002 (SYN)445
```

Would that make it easier?

Any suggestions would be great,

Thanks.

Comment: you can't because there is no way to know where finish the last number of the ip and where begins the port number. For the example you gave, the result can be: ip = 192.168.1.25, port: 4445. But perhaps have you more informations about this format.

Comment: If I manage to move the port to the end behind the (SYN) can it be done then?

Comment: Yes, but how will you make this move, it is the same problem.

Comment: I've changed the order in which the string was from the data so it can read with the port at the end.

Comment: Why you don't use simply a semi-colon as separator like this: 192.168.1.254:445 (the most common format). And why do you need a regex to extract informations since you seem to have an access to these informations?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte probably much easier as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

For this input:

```
192.168.1.254... 0000 0000 0010 = Flags: 0x002 (SYN)445
```

...use this:

```
(?<ip>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}).*Flags:\s\d{1}x\d{3}\s\((?<flag>\w+)\)(?<port>\d+)
```

...for an IP address with a port in this format:

```
192.168.1.254:445... 0000 0000 0010 = Flags: 0x002 (SYN)
```

...use this:

```
(?<ip>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}):(?<port>\d+).*Flags:\s\d{1}x\d{3}\s\((?<flag>\w+)\)
```

Comment: Just tested the first regex out with the port number at the end. It works for all data that contains one flag e.g. (SYN) but there are some that contain (SYN,ACK) or (RST,ACK). is there anyway to adapt this expression to include these?

Comment: You should be able to do it with a simple character class (I.e. change \w+ to [\w,]+). I tweaked the expression (pending admin approval), but haven't tested it.