# Dynamic guid extraction using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Hi all I need to extract Guid from the following string

`<PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName='fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247' runat='server'></PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue>
<PageFieldRichImageField:RichImageField FieldName="3de94b06-4120-41a5-b907-88773e493458" runat="server"></PageFieldRichImageField:RichImageField>`
What i need is to get is "fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" and "3de94b06-4120-41a5-b907-88773e493458" in this case, However this guid is dynamic and will change every time and there are lot more guids in the string that i have and I need to get all those guids so that I can add them to a colection. 
Note: The string is actually an aspx page content. All nodes are different but have same property "FieldName" which I need to get.

I went through the link [C# RegEx string extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436381/c-sharp-regex-string-extraction) and construcked the regex in same way. Here is what I did :

```
string s = @"<PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName='fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247' runat='server'>
        </PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue>";
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"FieldName=(?<ReferenceId>{36})");
        Match match = reg.Match(s);
        string guid = match.Groups["ReferenceId"].Value;
```

How ever this didnt work for me. I get exception"parsing "FieldName=(?{35})" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing." while creating the Regex object "reg".

If i dont use {36} which is suppose to be the length of GUiD:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"FieldName=(?<ReferenceId>)")
```

I dont get any exception but I dnt get desired result either. match.Groups["ReferenceId"].Value returns empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using sth. like that:

```
(?<=FieldName=['"])[a-f\d]{8}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{12}(?=['"])
```

### Explanation

1. `(?<=FieldName=['"])` prepended by *FieldName=* and *"* or *'*
2. `[a-f\d]{8}-[a-f\d]`**[...]** followed by GUID (which is what is actually matching)
3. `(?=['"])` followed by *"* or *'*

See this [in action at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/R12AOr/2)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is basically that you are providing the quantifier {36} but are not telling it what to quantify - you need some character matching expression right before the quantifier. For, example I just added the '.' before {36} in your example (meaning "match any 36 characters") and it seems to work. Oh, and I also added the missing apostrophe after "FieldName=":

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"FieldName='(?<ReferenceId>.{36})");
```

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/1tbien/1