# How to Retrieve a substring of numbers leading before another substring

Tags: c#, regex

I am extremely new to regular expressions so please bear with me,

I have certain strings in the below formats

```
"Lot Containing 450 Acres" 
**OUTPUT:** 450
"3 flats have an area of 50 Acres" etc.
**OUTPUT:** 50
"LOT CONTAINING 0.44 ACRES"
**OUTPUT:** 0.44
```

My requirement is to extract the number occuring before '`Acres`'.

I am aware that this can be done by using various `STRING` class methods like substring,contains,Char.IsDigit etc.

But it seems to be very tedious process,

can some one help me with a better approach ,preferably using `Regex`?

**EDIT 1:**

Solution Suggested by @MongZhu works perfectly for all integers except decimals. I have tried modifying his solution a little to make it work for decimals,

```
 string input = "3.96 ACRES" ;
 string pattern = @"(\d+[.]\d+)(?=\sACRES)";

 "LOT CONTAINING 0.44 ACRES"
 OUTPUT: 0.44
```

But

```
"Lot Containing 450 Acres" 
OUTPUT:
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436381/c-sharp-regex-string-extraction) is what you need. Use something like `(\d+)\s*Acres`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to match the number and the word assined to groups using parentheses in your pattern:

```
string input = "Lot Containing 450 Acres" ;

string pattern = @"(\d+)(\sAcres)";
```

Patter explanation:

`\d+` matches one or more occurences of a digit
`\s` matches exactly one white-space character

```
// test output  
foreach (Group group in Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
}
```

Output:

> 450 Acres
>   450
>    Acres

As you see the second group has the value that you need. Access it via: `Groups[1]`

```
string number = Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups[1].Value;
```

Or you could use [Looklahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) and match only if the number is followed by a space and the word `Acres`:

```
string pattern = @"(\d+)(?=\sAcres)";

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value);
```

Output:

> 450

**Edit:**

If you need to match decimal numbers, then you need to include an optional pattern : [dot followed by one or more numbers]: `(\.\d+)*`

Explanation:

`\.` matches a dot
`(\.\d+)*` matches zero or more occurences of the parenthesis content. The asterisk `*` makes the decimal numbers optional

Another way of making a match optional is to use `?` behind the pattern: `(\.\d+)?`. This will give you the same result

Comment: Thank you mong, that does work except for one condition where the string is "Lot Containing 3.49 Acres". For such strings it gives only values after the decimal i.e. 49 where as i need 3.49.

Comment: @Shekar.gvr then you should edit your post and add this example. I will edit my answer to accomodate the decimal number. But from my given example you should be able to figure out it yourself

Comment: regular-expressions.info should get you the rest of the way.  :-)

Comment: @MongZhu I have tried using this @"(\d+[.]\d+)(?=\sACRES)" which gives me the correct result for only decimal values but not for integers

Comment: @Shekar.gvr you need to make it optional by using either `*` or `?`

Comment: Yes, thanks @MongZhu, this @"(\d+[.]\d+)*(\d+)(?=\sACRES)" works perfectly

Comment: @Shekar.gvr glad to hear. Here is the pattern I use: `string pattern = @"(\d+(\.\d+)?)(?=\s*Acres)";`

Comment: @MongZhu for some reason that pattern that you said you use is not working for my inputs. But the one i previously mentioned does work. So thanks for making me get to the answer instead of directly spoonfeeding.

Comment: @Shekar.gvr you are welcome. That is strange. It works when I test it. hmm so be it :)