# How to Split String type Coordinates

Tags: c#

I have a string like this :

> {X=484,Y=488}

How can i split it to get 484 and 488 out ? and Int it in ***A and B*** ( A = 484, B = 488 )

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [C# RegEx string extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436381/c-sharp-regex-string-extraction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Split(',')` method to split the initial string where the comma appears and then extract from the splitted strings the digits using Linq `Where` and `Char.IsDigit`.The method `int.TryParse` is doing the conversion from `string` to `int` and is initializing the variables `a` and `b` and assigning the parsed values to them.

```
string str = "{ X = 484, Y = 488 }";

var result = str.Split(',');

int.TryParse(new String(result[0].Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()), out int a);
int.TryParse(new String(result[1].Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()), out int b);
```